# Using c# HttpClient in WebService calling other WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, wcf-rest

I'm writing a RESTful WebServiceA. In order to handle client's request it should call WebServiceB or WebServiceC or WebServiceD. I'm thinking about using HttpClient in WebServiceA to call other services using PostAsync() method.

There are quite a lot articles saying that HttpClient should be re-used as much as possible during the application's lifetime, but these articles seem to be about desktop applications.

Suppose Client1 would call WebServiceA and his call was forwarded to WebServiceB, same time Client2 calls and his call was forwarded to WebServiceC using the same static HttpClient object. Would this object deal with requests correctly in parallel and would a this object's methods be thread-safe in given context?

For test purposes I've made a static HttpClient object in WebServiceA and called WebServiceA's methods from console app in parallel. So far seems to be working OK. However I'm still not sure whether to use a static HttpClient or create and dispose good old HttpWebRequest/Response objects per call. Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is called a ``chatty`` application and is a [behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737536(v=vs.85).aspx) that one should try to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well, i'm not sure how to avoid being 'chatty' in WebService as it needs to answer to every call :)